# How to use fmdb for a login page?

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

I have a login page that has 2 textfields for username & password and a few buttons. I want to know that how I can use fmdb for checking if the username/password combination exists in my database? I also have another viewcontroller used for the user registeration page, having 4 textfields for username, password, email, contact number and a button to input the entered text into the database. How can I save the entered text in 4 fields to the database? Thanks in advance. Here is my code:
I succeeded in entering the data into the database,in the registerViewController but I want to enter code into the "btnforgot"(forgot Password) action  if the user forgets the password and/or username. I've been successful somewhat in the loginViewController too,as far as checking if the username & password match the same in the database or not,but i guess i am missing something(some code) in between.

```
LOGINVIEW


#import "loginViewController.h"
#import "carTypeViewController.h"
#import "registerViewController.h"
#import "FMDatabase.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FMDatabaseAdditions.h"
@interface loginViewController ()

@end
@implementation loginViewController
@synthesize lblPass,lblUserName,txtPass,txtUser;
```

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
    {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
    }

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
self.title = @"Enter Credentials";
username = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
password = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"];
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

[database open];

BOOL success = NO;

    NSInteger count = [database intForQuery:@"select count(*) from RegMembers where USERNAME = ? and PASSWORD = ?", username, password];

if ([txtUser.text length] == 0 || [txtPass.text length]== 0){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Kindly enter details in all fields" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}

else if (count > 0)
{
        success = YES;

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Welcome" message:@"Login successful" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

        carTypeViewController *car = [[carTypeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"carTypeViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:car animated:YES];

}
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Kindly enter the correct credentials" message:@"Entered username or password is incorrect" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert1 show];

        txtUser.text=@"";
        txtPass.text=@"";
    }
[database close];
}
-(IBAction)removeKeyboard
{
[self.txtUser resignFirstResponder];
[self.txtPass resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)btnSignUp:(id)sender {
registerViewController *reg = [[registerViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"registerViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:reg animated:YES];
}


- (IBAction)btnExit:(id)sender {
exit(1);

}

- (IBAction)btnForgotPass:(id)sender {
}

@end






REGISTERVIEW

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.title = @"Create Account";
[super viewDidLoad];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,      NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"];
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

[database open];

[database executeUpdate:@"create table if not exists RegMembers (ID INTEGER NOT NULL     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT 0, USERNAME TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL , PASSWORD TEXT NOT NULL     , EMAIL TEXT NOT NULL , NUMBER TEXT  NOT NULL)"];

[database close];
}
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(IBAction)removeKeyboard
{
[self.txtUname resignFirstResponder];
[self.txtPass resignFirstResponder];
[self.txtEmail resignFirstResponder];
[self.txtNumber resignFirstResponder];

}
- (IBAction)btnUAcount:(id)sender
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"contacts.db"];
FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];

if ([txtUname.text length] == 0 ||
    [txtPass.text length]== 0   ||
    [txtEmail.text length]== 0  ||
    [txtNumber.text length]== 0)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Kindly     enter details in all fields" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];

}
else

{
    if ([database open])
    {

        [database executeUpdate:@"insert into RegMembers(username, password, email,     number) values(?,?,?,?)",
        [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@",txtUname.text],[NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtPass.text],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtEmail.text],    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txtNumber.text],nil];
        if (1)
        {
            NSLog(@"contact added");
            self.txtUname.text = @"";
            self.txtPass.text = @"";
            self.txtEmail.text = @"";
            self.txtNumber.text = @"";
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"failed to add contact");
        }

    }
    [database close];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Registeration succesful"     message:@"Thanks for choosing edmunds" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"     otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check to see if the userid/password combination is in your database, you can:

```
#import "FMDatabaseAdditions"
```

and then you can see if the userid/password combination qualifies as a successful login like so:

```
BOOL success = NO;

NSInteger count = [database intForQuery:@"select count(*) from RegMembers where USERNAME = ? and PASSWORD = ?", username, password];

if (count > 0)
    success = YES;
```

Having said that, I have a couple of observations ranging from the trivial to the critical:

1. Right now you're always reporting "contact added". You should really determine whether the insert succeeded or not. You can do this by checking the value returned by the `executeUpdate` method (returns `YES` if successful, `NO` if the `INSERT` failed).
2. When using a `PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` key, you should not use `DEFAULT 0`. First, I don't think that accomplishes anything (it will start at `1`, regardless). Second, even if it did, it would be very bad to use zero because FMDB's `lastInsertRowId`, which calls SQLite `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid`, uses zero value for the numeric key to designate an error. So, never use zero.
3. Far more critical, you should *never* store passwords on the device unencrypted. (Even if you don't care about the security of your app, too many users re-use passwords, so you want to make sure that you don't become a possible way for their password to be compromised.)

   At the very least, you'd want to encrypt the password when you store it in the database, and then, when logging in, encrypt the password that the user provided, and compare the two encrypted passwords. If you want to see some of the cryptographic services available, see the [Cryptographic Services Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/cryptoservices/).
4. Having said that, you might not even want to write any password encryption code yourself (to do this properly is not entirely trivial).

   Using the iOS Keychain is probably better. Apple's primer on the topic is the WWDC 2013 video [Protecting Secrets with the Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/#709).

   For example, to save the password, email address, and number associated with a userid, you could do something like:

   ```
   // see if the userid already exists

   NSDictionary* query = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass       : (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                           (__bridge id)kSecAttrService : @"com.domain.app",
                           (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount : self.useridTextField.text,
                           (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit  : (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne,
                           (__bridge id)kSecReturnData  : @NO};

   OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, NULL);

   if (status == errSecSuccess)
   {
       [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"That userid is already registered" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
       return;
   }

   // create payload of secret data

   NSDictionary *secret = @{@"password" : self.passwordTextField.text ?: [NSNull null],
                            @"email"    : self.emailTextField.text    ?: [NSNull null],
                            @"number"   : self.numberTextField.text   ?: [NSNull null]};

   NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:secret];

   // create keychain query

   query = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass       : (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
             (__bridge id)kSecAttrService : @"com.domain.app",
             (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount : self.useridTextField.text,
             (__bridge id)kSecValueData   : data};

   // add data associated with the userid in the keychain

   status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, NULL);
   NSAssert(status == errSecSuccess, @"%s: SecItemAdd error: %lu", __FUNCTION__, (unsigned long)status);
   ```

   Then, when you want to log in, you can do something like:

   ```
   BOOL success = NO;

   NSDictionary* query = @{(__bridge id)kSecClass       : (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                           (__bridge id)kSecAttrService : @"com.domain.app",
                           (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount : self.useridTextField.text,
                           (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimit  : (__bridge id)kSecMatchLimitOne,
                           (__bridge id)kSecReturnData  : @YES};

   CFTypeRef typeRef;

   OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, &typeRef);

   // if we found keychain entry for that userid, check the password

   if (status == noErr)
   {
       NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:(__bridge NSData *)typeRef];
       NSAssert(dictionary, @"%s: unarchiveObjectWithData failed: %@", __FUNCTION__, (__bridge NSData *)typeRef);
       NSString *password = dictionary[@"password"];
       if ([self.passwordTextField.text isEqualToString:password])
           success = YES;

       CFRelease(typeRef);
   }

   // if we didn't succeed for any reason, tell the user

   if (!success)
   {
       [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Login failed" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil] show];
   }
   ```

Comment: well i agree with the advice you gave me in text,but to be frank i am new to database/fmdb a well as ios.

Comment: i am sure i didnt get anything from the code section other than the alertview,nsdictionary & basic/regular ios code.a link to some basic tutorials would be appreciated. secondly a simpler solution/answer,despite not o high level code will help me,though everyone's advice here helps me learn a lot. :-D

Comment: @Neelang At the start of my answer, I show you how to look up the userid/password in the database (despite my serious misgivings about storing the password unencrypted). BTW, FMDB supports [SQLiteEncrypt](http://www.sqlite-encrypt.com/develop-guide.htm) (which you have to buy separately), so that might be another solution for encrypting your database if you don't want to tackle the Keychain solution. In terms of good tutorials on the frighteningly complex topic of doing encryption properly, I can only refer you to that WWDC video I linked to in my answer. Good luck!

Comment: i understand your concern and advice about the security of app,and encryption etc.but this login page is part of my really important project that i've to submit asap,so i guess if you can just forget the security/encryption etc for a while & help me with an easy ,simple solution.though i have great regard for your perfectly right advice.

Comment: @Neelang Then the `intForQuery` code at the start of my answer is all your login screen needs to do in order to confirm whether the userid/password combination is found in the database. So, when the user taps on the "login" button, having entered the username and password, just do `intForQuery` to confirm whether its found in the database or not. (If this is for demo purposes, you can forgo the encryption. But if production app, it's inadvisable.)

Comment: i entered your "intForQuery" code at the instead of my "query" and other code but now it isnt allowing me to login despite entering the correct username/password.i'll edit the question and enter the new code(edited as per your advice).

Comment: and ya @Rob it's a demo app,for my project submission at institute.  ;-)

Comment: this is a humble request from me to have a look at this post and spend some of your valuable time to resolve this,as my app is almost ready except for this view and i am unable to finish it.  I entered your "intForQuery" code at the instead of my "query" and other code but now it isnt allowing me to login despite entering the correct username/password.i'll edit the question and enter the new code(edited as per your advice).the code is posted by me as per your suggestion. A big thanks in advance.

Comment: @Neelang You should examine the contents of the `username` and `password` variables that you use in your `INSERT` SQL. Your code checks to see if `([txtUser.text length] == 0 || [txtPass.text length] == 0)`, but then your `intForQuery` doesn't use those text fields, but rather those separate `username` and `password` variables, which are very confusingly initialized as mutable arrays (and even more confusingly, apparently never populated). Just use your two text fields rather than those `username` and `password` variables.

Comment: you just ended a silly but troublesome issue,if you dont mind can you guide me further for saving items the logged in user selects from a tableview,into the database with the date & time of selection on click of a button which is on another view,whose action and navigation code for that view are already created.i didnt create a new question as i wasnt able to write the code for what i wanted and the explanation was too long!you are familiar with the app's design and can help me,so expecting a favour from you.regards.

Comment: @Neelang You really should give it a go. I'm sure you'll get it. It's not that hard. Look at `fmdb.m` for examples.