# Getting to show images in tableview's cells on the next view controller

Tags: ios, uitableview

**DETAILVIEW**
here's the detailview code showing the erroneous sections.howing the details of different sections of cars,such as suv,sedan,hatchback.this code show different cars of types of suvs,sedans,hatchbacks in forms of a

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    Hatchback = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Hyundai i10",@"Hyundai i20",@"Maruti Suzuki Swift",@"Maruti Suzuki wagonR",@"Honda brio",@"Ford figo", nil];


    SUV = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Tata safari storme",@"Mahindra scorpio",@"Mahindra xuv 500",@"Renault duster", nil];


    Sedan = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Honda city",@"Maruti Suzuki dzire",@"Hyundai verna",@"Skoda octavia",@"Honda civic",@"Honda amaze",@" Ford fiesta", nil];



    HatchbackImg = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"i10.jpg",@"i20.jpg",@"Swift.jpeg",@"wagonR.jpg",@"brio.jpg",@"figo.jpg",@"indica.jpg",@"beat.jpg",nil];


    SUVImg = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"safari.jpg",@"scorpio.jpg",@"xuv.jpg",@"duster.jpg", nil];


    SedanImg = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"city.jpg",@"dzire.jpg",@"verna.jpg",@"octavia.jpg",@"civic.jpg",@"amaze.jpg",@"fiesta.jpg", nil];


    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

    #pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}




- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    //return 0;
    if (Carint ==0) {
        return [Hatchback count];
    } else if (Carint ==1) {
        return [SUV count];
    } else if (Carint ==2) {
        return [Sedan count];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
- (UIImage *)imageForRow:(NSUInteger)row
{
    if (Carint == 0) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:[HatchbackImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    } else if (Carint == 1) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:[SUVImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    } else if (Carint == 2) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:[SedanImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    return nil;
}

- (NSString *)titleForRow:(NSUInteger)row
{
    if (Carint == 0) {
        return [Hatchback objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else if (Carint == 1) {
        return [SUV objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else if (Carint == 2) {
        return [Sedan objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return nil;
}

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

        cell.textLabel.text = [self titleForRow:indexPath.row];
        cell.imageView.image = [self imageForRow:indexPath.row];

        if (Carint == 0) {
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[HatchbackImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            cell.textLabel.text =[Hatchback objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
        } else if (Carint == 1) {
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[SUVImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            cell.textLabel.text = [SUV objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
        } else if (Carint == 2) {
            cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[SedanImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            cell.textLabel.text = [Sedan objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
        }
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }

     // Configure the cell...
    return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBg1.png"]];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
}


    #pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (Carint == 0)
    {
       NSString *imageName = [HatchbackImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //[UIImageView setImage:[SedanImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

     //  [UIImageView setImage:[SedanImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    }
    else if (Carint ==1)
    {
        NSString *imageName = [SUVImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    else if (Carint ==2)
    {
        NSString *imageName = [SedanImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }

    NSString *carName = [self titleForRow:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *carImage = [self imageForRow:indexPath.row];

    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

    carSelectViewController *carDetailViewController = [[carSelectViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"carSelectViewController" bundle:nil];

    carDetailViewController.carName = carName;
    carDetailViewController.carImage = carImage;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:carDetailViewController animated:YES];

}

@end
```

Comment: You should edit this question to be more clear, and show relevant code -- I don't see any table view code here, or where you tried to pass an image to the next controller.

Comment: I'm on my phone atm but it appears that you have put the code for `imageForRow` inside the code for `cellForRow...`. This is a method implementation so should not be inside another method implementation.

Comment: OK, now I'm back on a laptop I can see that you've done something really weird here. You seem to have pasted code into random bits of your code. Look at my `cellForRowAtIndexpath` code. It is about 10 lines of code. I have deleted all the `Carint` stuff. That `Carint` should only every be referenced inside the new functions. Plus, you've put the functions inside `cellForRow` etc... Just go through your code. For each method I have written in my answer just delete the WHOLE method and paste mine in instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be storing data in the cells of a table. The cells of a table are there to display information.

First, you seem to be using an iVar `Carint` to display different sets of cars. First, all variables should have lowercase first letters. Second, this is a bad idea.

By doing this you are strongly coupling the table to the data it is displaying. I'll ignore this for now though.

Second, you should also be using a custom UITableViewCell subclass to create `UIImageViews` etc... but I'll ignore this too.

Third, you should create a Class called `Car`. Then give the class `Car` two properties, `name` and `image` and actually you could give it `type` too but again I'll ignore this.

**NOTE** just because I am ignoring them doesn't mean you should too. Think of these first three as hints of what to work on next.

Fourth, create a function that will return the image for the row. Like this...

```
- (UIImage *)imageForRow:(NSUInteger)row
{
    if (Carint == 0) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:[HatchbackImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    } else if (Carint == 1) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:[SUVImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    } else if (Carint == 2) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:[SedanImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

and the title. Like this...

```
- (NSString *)titleForRow:(NSUInteger)row
{
    if (Carint == 0) {
        return [Hatchback objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else if (Carint == 1) {
        return [SUV objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else if (Carint == 2) {
        return [Sedan objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

This means that you can change your current methods like so...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self titleForRow:indexPath.row];
    cell.imageView.image = [self.imageForRow:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

and...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *carName = [self titleForRow:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *carImage = [self imageForRow:indexPath.row];        

    // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

    // OMG! Fix the naming conventions. Class names should start with uppercase letters.
    carSelectViewController *carDetailViewController = [[carSelectViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"carSelectViewController" bundle:nil];

    // These won't work until you do the next bit.
    carDetailViewController.carName = carName;
    carDetailViewController.carImage = carImage;

    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: carDetailViewController animated:YES];    
}
```

Next, add properties to the "detail view controller" like this...

```
@interface carSelectViewController : UIViewController

    @property NSString *carName;
    @property UIImage *carImage;

@end
```

These are then being set by the previous view controller.

Finally, use the values of these properties to display the data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.title = self.carName;
    imageView.image = self.carImage;

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

For more information about doing this and especially working on those first three points you can see here...

http://www.raywenderlich.com

Comment: can u explain in terms of code!i mean what to edit & where to edit?let me explain what my code does:

Comment: @Neelang ok, will edit my answer. I had to spend about 15 mins editing your question to fully understand what was happening. Make sure you format code properly. :)

Comment: my sincere apologies,for troubling you.but as i am new to this concept so try and understand and help me understand this concept of formatting code.thanks & sorry.

Comment: i did changes as per your advice but there's a problem:

Comment: i did changes as per your advice but there's a problem: i cant change "carselectviewcontroller" to "nsobject",as it is of type uiviewcontroller.and secondly your code is giving 3 errors:1.use of undeclared identifier imageForRow(in detailViewController).  2. and 3. no visible interface for cardetailViewController declares the selector imageForRow.(in the lines where *carname,*carImage are declared.).

Comment: Sorry, yes that shuld be UIViewController not NSObject. You should not be using [detailViewController imageForRow] anywhere. I am using [selg imageForRow:]

Comment: no no,you are not getting me,i typed the code as typed by you above,let me explain: when i type the "- (UIImage *)imageForRow:(NSUInteger)row" line in the carDetailViewcontroller inside the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method ,i get that error, and  about the other two i already mentioned.  let me againg emphasize that there i a tableview named "carTypeViewcontroller"navigating to another tableview "carDetailViewController",and then a simple uiviewcontroller "carSelectViewcontroller",to how the image,label and button.

Comment: Yes, the only code that goes in the detail view controller is the stuff to display the image and title (and the properties). Everything else goes in the table view controller.

Comment: Again. Your naming conventions are making this harder. All this code goes in the cardetailviewcontroller. Only the last two bits go in the carselectviewcontroller.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting about the methods. Only one of them and copy paste te whole thing.

Comment: in the carDetailViewController,there's an error: "use of undeclared identifier:imageForRow, the other two errors are:"no visible @interface for carDetailViewController declares the selector 'imageForRow' ".all the errors are related to "imageForRow",as you can see.i apologized for the naming conventions before,so no good to mention it again & again,i guess.and ya i mentioned everything about the errors already in the previous comments of mine,if u remember :-D

Comment: Oh, I just had another look. I put a full stop in there. Just remove that. Ie self.imageForRow should be self imageForRow

Comment: my dear friend,i guess i can call u that after troubling you so much, :-D at no place in any file in my code there is a statement "self.imageForRow". and ya 1 error is also for "titleForRow",along with "imageForRow".your last idea was of no help!i am sorry for that.

Comment: in the 4th image you posted above,the lines:  NSString *carName = [self titleForRow:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *carImage = [self imageForRow:indexPath.row];"

Comment: in the 4th image you posted above,the lines:  NSString *carName = [self titleForRow:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *carImage = [self imageForRow:indexPath.row];" compiler gives "ARC semantic issue" error,for both of the above lines & says "no visible interface found for selector imageForRow,and the same error for the selector titleForRow. for the other error look at 1st image where it says "- (UIImage *)imageForRow:(NSUInteger)row",for this statement it gives the error-: "use of undeclared identifier imageForRow".if you wish i can paste the code above by editing my question,for you to see it.

Comment: Yeah, paste your code from the detail view controller and I'll take a look.

Comment: it worked for a while,but now things are not working.can you please send me the code for the carSelectViewController(.h &.m) & carDetailViewController(.h &.m)

Comment: What isn't working in them? I'm not going to write them for you.

Comment: i miplaced the code,unintentionally,you dont need to write the code again but atleat can you reorder the code?please.anyways inspite of you doing it or not i'll accept your answer,as you helped me a ton.if you agree let me know sso that i can put the code for you else a denial will be good enough. :-)

Comment: i fixed it back,thanks,but i found another way of doing what we did!i am answering my question beow.plz have a look and let me know which method is better.

Answer (score 0):

```
**CARDETAILVIEWCONTROLLER**
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[self showData];
[super viewDidLoad];

self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor brownColor];
}
-(void) showData
{
Hatchback = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

SUV = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

Sedan = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


//Hatchback

[Hatchback addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hyundai i10",@"name",@"i10.jpg",@"image",nil]];

[Hatchback addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hyundai i20",@"name",@"i20.jpg",@"image",nil]];

[Hatchback addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Maruti Suzuki Swift",@"name",@"Swift.jpeg",@"image",nil]];

[Hatchback addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Maruti Suzuki wagonR",@"name",@"wagonR.jpg",@"image",nil]];

[Hatchback addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Honda Brio",@"name",@"brio.jpg",@"image",nil]];
[Hatchback addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Ford figo",@"name",@"figo.jpg",@"image",nil]];

//SUV

[SUV addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Tata safari storme",@"name",@"safari.jpg",@"image",nil]];


[SUV addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mahindra scorpio",@"name",@"scorpio.jpg",@"image",nil]];

[SUV addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Mahindra xuv 500",@"name",@"xuv.jpg",@"image",nil]];

[SUV addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Renault duster",@"name",@"duster.jpg",@"image",nil]];

//Sedan

[Sedan addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Honda city",@"name",@"city.jpg",@"image",nil]];

[Sedan addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"MarutiSuzuki dzire",@"name",@"dzire.jpg",@"image",nil]];

[Sedan addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Hyundai verna",@"name",@"verna.jpg",@"image",nil]];

[Sedan addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Skoda octavia",@"name",@"octavia.jpg",@"image",nil]];

[Sedan addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Honda civic",@"name",@"civic.jpg",@"image",nil]];

[Sedan addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Honda amaze",@"name",@"amaze.jpg",@"image",nil]];

[Sedan addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Ford fiesta",@"name",@"fiesta.jpg",@"image",nil]];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
if (Carint ==0) {
    return [Hatchback count];
}
if (Carint ==1) {
    return [SUV count];
}
if (Carint ==2) {
    return [Sedan count];
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];


    if (Carint == 0)
    {
        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[HatchbackImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.textLabel.text =[[Hatchback objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }
    if (Carint == 1)
    {
        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[SUVImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.textLabel.text = [[SUV objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    if (Carint == 2)
    {
        cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[SedanImg objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.textLabel.text = [[Sedan objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]objectForKey:@"name"];
    }

    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
}

return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBg1.png"]];
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
carSelectViewController *car = [[carSelectViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"carSelectViewController" bundle:nil];

if (Carint == 0)
{
    car.carImageString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[Hatchback objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]];
    car.carLabelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[Hatchback objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]];
    car.title = [[Hatchback objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name" ];

}
else if (Carint ==1)
{
    car.carImageString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[SUV objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]];
    car.carLabelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[SUV objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]];

    car.title = [[SUV objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name" ];

}
else if (Carint ==2)
{
    car.carImageString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[Sedan objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]];
    car.carLabelString = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[[Sedan objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"image"]];

    car.title = [[Sedan objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"name" ];

}
[self.navigationController pushViewController:car animated:YES];
}
@end

**CARSELECTVIEWCONTROLLER


@synthesize carImageString,carLabelString;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
NSString *localImgName;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
carImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:carImageString];
carLabel.text = carLabelString;
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnBook:(id)sender {
carBookViewController *Book = [[carBookViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"carBookViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: Book animated:YES];
}
@end
```

I have tried the method of using nsdictionaries for key pair values of images & text together to make the code simpler(i guess).it goes well with the requirement of the app as well to show text & images together on the next view.

Comment: This is the same as my answer except it needs refactoring. You have the phrase `if (Carint == 1) ... if (Carint ==2) ... if (Carint == 3)` several times and you're doing the same thing each time. (i.e. just getting the image or text). If you refactor these into separate methods then you cut down on number of lines and you have exactly my solution.

Comment: thanks again bro,i needed your help with another thing here in my other question,i am on the verge of success on this one but something minor is wrong,here's the link. "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874024/how-to-use-fmdb-for-a-login-page"

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NextViewController *viewcontroller=[NextViewController alloc]init];
viewcontroller.image=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].imageView.image;

}
```

Then either push or present this view Controller to show.

viewcontroller.image is cusotm property in ur next class
 then on viewdidload method

set the imageView's image property to self.image

Comment: No, you should not be storing data in the view.

Comment: why cant.? for simply sending the image u can send that image to next viewController. through its property