# How to use FMDB to save data in SQLite database?

Tags: ios, sqlite, uitableview, fmdb

I have a car rental app that uses [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). After the user logs in (authenticated against the database), the user navigates to multiple tableviews, one after another. In the 2nd tableview he can select a car from cells showing car's name, on tapping any cell, next view i shown with car image, and a button to proceed to next view having a datapicker to select date & time when the car is booked and a button to show the car name, image and date & time of selection to be used for history of user.

How can I save the text & image related to that cell in the database with the date & time of booking?

Comment: @Neellang So you want to send data like: date of booking, name, car model etc to the server but you dont know how to do that?

Comment: While I understand you're new to S.O., in the future I'd encourage you to do a little more research on your own, look at samples (e.g. FMDB includes examples in `fmdb.m` or search online or on S.O., specifically) and then really give it a good faith attempt yourself before posting a question. And while it's good that you provided a code sample, this has way too much unrelated code and doesn't exhibit any attempt at the actual problem, the saving of the data. We want to help, but questions like this will only serve to raise the ire of the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the basis of [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874024/how-to-use-fmdb-for-a-login-page), I infer you're asking how to save data using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). Take a look at the `fmdb.m` file for tons of wonderful examples.

For example, this is you create a table:

```
BOOL success;

success = [db executeUpdate:@"create table if not exists test (a text, b text, c integer, d double, e double)"];

if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"%s: create table error: %@", __FUNCTION__, [db lastErrorMessage]);

    // do whatever you want upon error
}
```

This is how you insert data (including a date):

```
success = [db executeUpdate:@"insert into test (a, b, c, d, e) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" ,
        @"hi'", // look!  I put in a ', and I'm not escaping it!
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"number %d", i],
        [NSNumber numberWithInt:i],
        [NSDate date],
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.2f]];

if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"%s: insert error: %@", __FUNCTION__, [db lastErrorMessage]);

    // do whatever you need to upon error
}
```

And then they show you how to retrieve the information (including the date):

```
FMResultSet *rs = [db executeQuery:@"select rowid,* from test where a = ?", @"hi'"];

if (!rs) {
    NSLog(@"%s: select error: %@", __FUNCTION__, [db lastErrorMessage]);

    // do whatever you want upon error

    return;
}

while ([rs next]) {
    // just print out what we've got in a number of formats.
    NSLog(@"%d %@ %@ %@ %@ %f %f",
          [rs intForColumn:@"c"],
          [rs stringForColumn:@"b"],
          [rs stringForColumn:@"a"],
          [rs stringForColumn:@"rowid"],
          [rs dateForColumn:@"d"],
          [rs doubleForColumn:@"d"],
          [rs doubleForColumn:@"e"]);
}

[rs close];
```

You should give this a go using your own table (with meaningful table and column names), but this illustrates the basic techniques for creating, inserting, and selecting data.

---

For example, let's assume the table was defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reservation (reservation_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT, car_name TEXT, car_image_name TEXT, reservation_date DOUBLE)
```

You can then save a record in that table like so:

```
- (BOOL)saveReservationForUser:(NSString *)username carName:(NSString *)carName carImageName:(NSString *)carImageName reservationDate:(NSDate *)reservationDate
{
    BOOL success = [db executeUpdate:@"insert into reservation (username, car_name, car_image_name, reservation_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?)" ,
            username,
            carName,
            carImageName,
            reservationDate];

    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"%s: insert error: %@", __FUNCTION__, [db lastErrorMessage]);

        // do whatever you need to upon error
    }

    return success;
}
```

Note, I'm storing the car image filename, not the actual image, in the database. Frankly, the car image name probably doesn't even belong in this reservation table (you'd probably want a table of cars that maps between a car identifier number to the name and the image of the car). But hopefully this is enough to get you going.

Comment: thanks dear,i didnt knew that i could find examples in fmdb.m,and anyways it dosent help stripping off new user's reputation earned hard and discourages them badly.but if this is the culture & rules over here,i just dont care.

Comment: @Neelang if you edit the question, I'm happy to up vote it (I can't change vote unless it's edited, sadly).

Comment: thanks for your good gesture,may i know what should be the "question" like?i never knew what "exactly" to ask in form of question.and secondly my app is a demo app,o there'no server as such,in the app,i am just using xcode,sqlite,fmdb.so an explanation on how submit the required data to database(i guess through the sqlite queries that you wrote?).thanks & regards.

Comment: @Neelang The [Asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) pages have many good links. At a minimum, I'd suggest (a) referencing the fact that you're using FMDB, as that makes a big difference in the answer; (b) prune the sample code to the bare minimum to illustrate the problem (e.g. maybe just `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`), also making it clear what precisely you want to save (date and `carLabelString`?); and (c) make it clear what you've tried (i.e. demonstrate that you've done some research) and precisely what did or did not work. If you'd like me to try editing the question, let me know.

Comment: i dont mind you editing my question,but i have a question,the tableview navigates to the next view showing car's image in imageview & car's name as title navigating to next view with datepicker and button to submit the data.so how can i use the queries above in context with the "car selection from cells" in tableview.

Comment: i can send you the pics of the design of the app if you wish.but i cant upload pics here,as my reputation isnt 10.

Comment: @Neelang I tweaked your question, removing all of that unrelated `UITableView` code, hopefully distilling the question down to the [minimal essentials](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Frankly, a good question should illustrate what you've tried, but I don't know what you've tried thus far, so I couldn't supply that part.

Comment: I've also updated my answer with an example car reservation. This probably isn't quite right, either, but I don't know your full data model, but you'd probably have a table of cars (with numeric id, car name, image filename, etc.), and then store the numeric id for that car in your reservation table, not the car name and image. Regarding the saving of the reservation date and time, you can either construct a `NSDate` object and save that in your table, or store the day, month, year, hour, and minute in the `reservation` table, but that's up to you.

Comment: Regarding seeing screen snapshots of your app design, I don't really need to see that. I think I get the basic idea of the business problem. I think you should really distill your questions down to the fundamental programming question rather than broader app design question. We're here to help you with your code, not address the broader design questions.

Comment: i saw your example above,but i am confused about implementing it in my code,my data model implements a tableview with list of cars navigating to next view showing image of selected car from tableview & below it a date picker and two buttons,the concept is that the selected car's name,the username(of the user logged in to the app),date of car booking/reservation(when the button is clicked),get saved on the database,on click of first button(it books the car),and the second one to view user history(cars he has booked previously).your help is greatly appreciated,if you wish i can type code above.

Comment: @Neelang We should move this to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45373/how-to-use-fmdb-to-save-data-in-sqlite-database

Comment: ,i dont mind moving the discussion,but i couldnt figure out how to type in that chat window.can you help me?

Comment: i lost connectivity,so couldn't reply to you,i've posted some text message,in the chat window,kindly read it if you find some time,thanks.

Comment: which is the best & convenient free app to access stackoverflow posts on iPhone?

Comment: dear Rob thanks for all your help,i am marking your answer as the correct one and haven't found a way to show the date in non encrypted form in the database table,thanks ,i dont think anyone other that god would help me out of this mess,you are his angel for me thanks ,thanks a ton.regards & best wishes.hope i find some way to show the date unencrypted in the database table.

Comment: are you getting my chat messages?there was no reply from you so i thought may be you didn't.if you did get them and were busy then i am sorry for disturbing you.i am getting impatient ass the deadline for project submission is nearing and i am stuck at this last hurdle,which i hope to crosss with your help soon.please dont mind this disturbance from me(if it ever was) and help me finish this thing by helping and obliging me.thanks & regards.Neelang

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"UserDatabase.sqlite"];

FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:dbPath]];
[database open];
[database executeUpdate:@"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_INFO (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, EMAIL TEXT, PASSWORD TEXT, C_PASSWORD TEXT)"];
[database close];
```

Answer (score 0):

Save your data with necessary changes :

//Getting DB path
    NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docPathsStr = [pathArray objectAtIndex:0];

```
//Return our Database file path
NSString *appDBPathStr = [docPathsStr stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"employee.sqlite"];

//Create Sqlite DB
FMDatabase *aDatabase = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:appDBPathStr];
[aDatabase open];
NSString *aInsertQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES ('%@', '%@' ,'%@' ,'%@' ,'%@' )",myFirstnameStr,myLastnameStr,myEmailStr,myPasswordStr,myDOBStr];
[aDatabase executeUpdate:aInsertQuery];
[aDatabase close];
```